# android 2.1SDK - resize bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, image-resizing, bitmapfactory, forceclose

I download and resize my bitmap using the following code :

```
private void downloadImage(String urlImg, ImageView v) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null, resized= null;
    try {
        URL urlImage = new URL("http://.../" + urlImg);
        HttpURLConnection connexion = (HttpURLConnection) urlImage
                .openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = connexion.getInputStream();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, false);
        v.setImageBitmap(resized);

        connexion.disconnect();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and in my onCreate() function, I create dynamically ImageViews where i use my previous function

```
   ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
   downloadImage(list.getOneAnnonce(i).getPhoto(), view);
   trMain.addView(view);
```

if I dont try to resize bitmap, there is no error but if i try to resize -> Force close

Comment: Make sure that `bitmap` is an actual Bitmap and not `null` when you try to resize.

Comment: In fact, sometimes there isn't necessarily an image so the bitmap stays null. Thank you!